# How to Work zonedSchedule local notifications in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**Set to the notification**

**Used to the Flutter Local Notification Packages**

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

**I want to set same notification multiple time**

```
DateTime current = 2020-12-15 21:00:00.000;

NotificationUtils.showNotification1(
    time: current.subtract(Duration(days: 3)),
    );
NotificationUtils.showNotification1(
    time: current.subtract(Duration(hours: 24)),
    );
NotificationUtils.showNotification1(
    time: current.subtract(Duration(hours: 2)),
    );
NotificationUtils.showNotification1(
    time: current.subtract(Duration(minutes: 30)),
   );
NotificationUtils.showNotification1(
    time: current,
    );
```

**Local Notification Function**

```
class NotificationUtils {
static FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

static void configLocalNotification() {
  var androidInitilize = AndroidInitializationSettings('appstore');
  var iOSinitilize = IOSInitializationSettings();
  var initilizationsSettings = new InitializationSettings(android: androidInitilize, 
      iOS:iOSinitilize);
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initilizationsSettings,onSelectNotification: (String 
     payload) async {});
         }  

static Future showNotification1({DateTime time}) async {

var androidDetails = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
  "notification 1",
  "App Notification 1",
  "Notification 1",
  importance: Importance.max,
  priority: Priority.high,
  color: Colors.blue,
  playSound: true,
  // timeoutAfter: 5000,
);
var iSODetails = new IOSNotificationDetails();
var generalNotificationDetails =
    new NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iSODetails);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
  0,
  "App",
  "Notification",
  time,
  generalNotificationDetails,
  androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
);}
static Future<void> cancelNotification() async {
 await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(1);}}
```

Comment: Hi dude, Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you cannot pass DateTime object directly to the method "zonedSchedule" of flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin because it expects TZDateTime type. So what you should do is to convert your DateTime according to your timezone like that:

1. First initialize your  time zones
2. Set timezone current location

```
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
...
tz.initializeTimeZones();
tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation('Europe/Warsaw'));
var currentDateTime = tz.TZDateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours: 10));
```